# Python sqlite3 issue with passing multiple values in where clause for select statement

Tags: python, sqlite

When passing multiple values in WHERE clause for a select statement, I am getting an error instead of matching rows from the table.

Error is:
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

I have table with a

```
runno(int)  value(str)    sample(str)
100         Test File.1   Sample Value is 1
100         Test File.1   Sample Value is 2
100         Test File.2   Sample Value is 200
200         Test File.21  Sample Value is unknown
200         Test File.21  Sample Value is New
```

```
searchVal1 = ['Test File.1']
searchVal2 = [100] --- also tried ['100']
cur.execute("SELECT sample FROM table WHERE value=? AND runno=?", (searchVal1,searchVal2))
```

results in:
`sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`

However, if I just pass one value in WHERE clause it works:
`cur.execute("SELECT sample FROM table WHERE value=?", (searchVal1))`

or
`cur.execute("SELECT sample FROM table WHERE runno=?", (searchVal2))`

Sqlite3 version is: 3.21.0, python 3.7

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Table has 3 columns, runno(int), value(str),sample(str) with values like: runno=100, value=Test File.1, sample = Sample Value is 1 .... sorry the table with column headers and its value got typed in one line in my question above

Comment: `searchVal1` needs to be `int` type and `searchVal2` needs to be a `string`, but you are assigning both to a list: `searchVal1 = ['Test File.1']` and `searchVal2 = [100]`. Try `searchVal1 = 'Test File.1'` and `searchVal2 = 100`

Comment: Thank you Harry Cho, this works.